# UIKit's resignFirstResponder is almost or exactly like blur() in Javascript?

Tags: ios, uikit

I think `resignFirstResponder` is almost like `blur()` for Javascript?  And that's why we can say

```
[self.firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.lastNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.phoneNumberTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

all in a row, because it just "blurs" itself so that it is not focused.  So can we always remember `resignFirstResponder` is almost identical to `blur()` (or are they practically 100% identical?).  The reason is whenever I see `[aTextField resignFirstResponder]`, I always think of "the text field is now resigning some responder -- and the responder is... is it the keyboard?"... and it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `blur()` works. That sounds like a really horrible name to mean changing UI focus. But the first responder is the object which will be the first to get a chance to process an event. (It's the **first** to **respond** to an event - hence `firstRepsonder`.) When a view is sent a message to `resignFirstResponder`, it stops being the first object to process an event, and the next responder in the list of responders becomes the first responder. The [`Cocoa Event Handling Guide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i) explains it in detail.

Comment: so `resignAsFirstResponder` could be slightly more accurate?  Somehow, the method name `resignFirstResponder` always make me feel like it is resigning something else... (resigning another object)

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to look at it - `resignAsFirstResponder`.